# How to check if checkbox is checked without using getElementBy "id" or "name" attr?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I work with IE8 ONLY.

I have multiple check boxes , so i cannot write a separate `onchange` function for each .

Here is what i tried to do

**HTML**

```
<input checked type='checkbox' id='check1' onchange = 'checkChange()'>Ch1</input> 
<input checked type='checkbox' id='check2' onchange = 'checkChange()'>Ch2</input>
<input checked type='checkbox' id='check3' onchange = 'checkChange()'>Ch3</input>
```

**JS**

```
function checkChange() {
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
alert("Box " + $(this).id + " is checked");
}
else {
alert("Box " + $(this).id + " is unchecked");
}
}
```

It does not work properly. How can I get an alert message showing checkbox id that was checked or unchecked

Thanks

Comment: try using `$(this).prop('checked')`. this will return a true/false if the box is checked.

Comment: Pretty sure `$(this).is(':checked')` can be shortened to `this.checked`.

Comment: `$(this).id` should be `this.id` or `$(this).attr('id')`.

Comment: Thank you. But I did not get any alert messages. No error is thrown either

Comment: That HTML is invalid even in IE8, `input` is an empty tag, it can't have content or an end tag.

Comment: I tried `this.checked` this was my first attempt but it did not work . it was ignored by the browser with no error though .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is not related to the element which raised the event when using an `on*` handler, you need to pass it as a parameter:

```
<input checked="checked" type="checkbox" id="check1" onchange="checkChange(this)">Ch1
<input checked="checked" type="checkbox" id="check2" onchange="checkChange(this)">Ch2
<input checked="checked" type="checkbox" id="check3" onchange="checkChange(this)">Ch3
```

Then you can use it in your JS code:

```
function checkChange(that) {
    if ($(that).is(':checked')) {
        alert("Box " + that.id + " is checked");
    }
    else {
        alert("Box " + that.id + " is unchecked");
    }
}
```

You could also cut out the ugly attributes and use a pure jQuery implementation:

```
<input checked="checked" type="checkbox" id="check1" class="check">Ch1
<input checked="checked" type="checkbox" id="check2" class="check">Ch2
<input checked="checked" type="checkbox" id="check3" class="check">Ch3
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('.check').change(function() {
        var state = this.checked ? "checked" : "unchecked";
        alert("Box " + this.id + " is " + state);
    });
});
```

Comment: This is a very good explanation : `this is not related to the element which raised the event when using an on* handler, you need to pass it as a parameter` Thank You Now everything makes sense

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 <input checked type='checkbox' id='check1' onchange='checkChange(this)'>Ch1</input>


function checkChange(cbox) {
    if (cbox.checked == true) {
       ....
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `onchange` attributes.  Bind the event with JavaScript (jQuery).  You can add a class to all the checkboxes to bind to all of them at once:

```
<input checked type='checkbox' id='check1' class='checkChange'>Ch1
<input checked type='checkbox' id='check2' class='checkChange'>Ch2
<input checked type='checkbox' id='check3' class='checkChange'>Ch3

<script>
$(function(){
    $('.checkChange').change(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert("Box " + this.id + " is checked");
        }
        else {
            alert("Box " + this.id + " is unchecked");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Note that `$(this).id` is invalid.  It should be `this.id` or `$(this).prop('id')`.  Also, don't use `</input>`.  There is no closing tag for inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Use  a class:

```js
function checkChange() {
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
alert("Box " + this.id + " is checked");
}
else {
alert("Box " + this.id + " is unchecked");
}
}
$(".check").on("click",checkChange)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input checked type='checkbox' id='check1' class=check >Ch1</input> 
<input checked type='checkbox' id='check2' class=check >Ch2</input>
<input checked type='checkbox' id='check3' class=check >Ch3</input>
```

If you don't want to use class you can select inputs based on the beginning of the id `[id^=check]`

```js
function checkChange() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    alert("Box " + this.id + " is checked");
    }
    else {
    alert("Box " + this.id + " is unchecked");
    }
}
$("[id^=check]").on("click",checkChange)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=checkbox id=check1 checked>Ch1</input> 
<input type=checkbox id=check2 checked>Ch2</input>
<input type=checkbox id=check3 checked>Ch3</input>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      alert("Box " + $(this).id + " is checked");
   }
   else {
      alert("Box " + $(this).id + " is unchecked");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass a reference to self, then you can do whatever you want with it.

```
<input checked="" type="checkbox" id="check1" onchange="checkChange(this)">Ch1 
<input checked="" type="checkbox" id="check2" onchange="checkChange(this)">Ch2
<input checked="" type="checkbox" id="check3" onchange="checkChange(this)">Ch3

function checkChange(bx){  console.log(bx)  }
```